# Iterating through and Populating Named Ranges in Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I have a WinForms app written in C# and I want to programmatically export some data into the some named ranges in an Excel Template.  I've looked on these forums and elsewhere and the closest code I can find to what I want is as follows -

```
private Excel.Workbook m_workbook;
object missing = Type.Missing;

   public void testNamedRangeFind()
    {
        m_workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        int i = m_workbook.Names.Count;
        string address = "";
        string sheetName = "";

        if (i != 0)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Name name in m_workbook.Names)
            {
                string value = name.Value;
                //Sheet and Cell e.g. =Sheet1!$A$1 or =#REF!#REF! if refers to nothing
                string linkName = name.Name;
                //gives the name of the link e.g. sales
                if (value != "=#REF!#REF!")
                {
                    address = name.RefersToRange.Cells.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, missing, missing);
                    sheetName = name.RefersToRange.Cells.Worksheet.Name;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("" + value + ", " + linkName + " ," + address + ", " + sheetName);
            }
        }    
    }
```

However I get an error saying 'The name Globals does not exist in the current context'.

Can someone please explain what it is I am not understanding about this code, or alternatively point me at some other code that will enable me to post values from my Database into the Excel Template named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs on VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) and uses the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.

So you should create an Office Excel Workbook solution in Visual Studio:
`File` -> `New` -> `Visual C#` -> `Office` -> `[ Select your Office version ]` -> `Excel Workbook`